# Is there a Mercurial or Git version control plugin for PyScripter?

Tags: python, git, version-control, mercurial, pyscripter

I'm using Python 3.x and PyScripter to write my scripts. I really miss a version control feature in PyScripter - I got spoiled by Qt and MpLab X (I believe this is a subversion of Eclipse). Things were easy back than. Now I don't have any version control in PyScripter, but I do have Mercurial installed. I perfectly realise I can manage a Mercurial by hand, but I'm lazy and hate manual work. Any other sleak and smooth options I have? I'm ready to use any other vc system (e.g. git) - I just want to know what is the most painless way (proper one).

Comment: Is the command line really painful?  Both `git` and `mercurial` have reasonable simple command line syntax, and integration for both is available with a variety of popular editors.

Comment: "I'm lazy and hate manual work". Personally, I greatly prefer "hg commit" to a lot of clicking around in a GUI.

Comment: I'm as lazy as the next programmer, but with my setup, nearly all of Mercurial's power is (after getting a top-down terminal into focus with a single key) `hg cmd -a "few params"` = <20 key presses away. Even with modest typing speed, the overhead's about as tiny as it can get. The most common commands can be shortened to 2 or 3 characters, and are easily memorized.

Comment: @AndreBoos: Visual tools and IDE integration are a big deal when you have to do source digging. Bare command-line annotate is much less useful than an interactive (THG or web-based) annotate tools. The same applies to DAG rendering and analysis.

Comment: @Helgi Granted. I haven't worked on anything large enough to require those features, and I'm sure they do find use in larger projects. However, I think that Dccharacter would already be using a client with those features if he knew that he needed them.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I [just read this post](http://code.google.com/p/pyscripter/issues/detail?id=538) that suggests you can simply use the File Explorer menu of PyScripter, which automatically enables all of the functions from Windows Explorer.  I have TortoiseGIT installed, and you can see that from PyScripter's File Explorer window, the version control features of TortoiseGIT are enabled (possibly TortoiseHg as mentioned by @Helgi).

Browse to the folder where your python scripts are stored, make changes, commit-->master, all from right inside PyScripter.  Very simple!

[image: Run TortoiseGIT from PyScripter]

Answer (score 2):

As far as I understand, PyScripter has no Mercurial plugin, but it has configurable custom tool support.

For Windows Mercurial GUI, I highly recomment [TortoiseHg](http://tortoisehg.bitbucket.io/). It has a nice DAG renderer, visual annotate, file-by-file merge dialog, comes with KDiff3 bundled and integrates with other merge tools. It also displays overlays (clean, modified, added) on files in Windows Explorer.

For better integration with PyScripter, you can add certain calls to `thg` as custom tools:

- `thg ci` — open commit window
- `thg blame <file>` — annotate file (refer to the PyScripter to find out how to pass current file name to a tool)

**Caveat:** Without plugin, moved/renamed files won't be automatically noticed by Mercurial as such. You'll have to either find renames with the THG dialog, or move the files with Mercurial commands, outside of the IDE.

Maybe you will find this an acceptable substitute.

Answer (score 1):

I use Mercurial simply out of personal preference, but Git is probably equally suitable. It sounds like you're looking for a GUI that provides menus and buttons for some use cases, but I would suggest using the command line interface because it is faster and standard across platforms.

[A great introduction to Mercurial](http://hginit.com/)