# Version control with local file system (Windows) for Python

Tags: python, version-control, pyscripter

I write some scripts in Python with PyScripter and want to be able to created versions of my .py files without creating copies of the files on disk and managing them manually.

I know that there are some software used for that such GIT, SVN and some others. I have never used any version control software before. I don't have access to any server-based solution and want to be able to do this just on my local machine. It can be rather simple piece of software with no advanced functionality. Switching between different versions of code is a must, but it would be nice having a tool for finding differences in the code since last commit and alike.

I have access to Microsoft TFS though, but I was not able to find any way to connect PyScripter to TFS. I may consider using another Python IDE if there is comprehensive support for such a version control software I described above.

Comment: Well, pyscripter is poor in features compared to the pay-for IDEs (for example PyCharm or WingIDE). What I would recommend is to just use local GIT repository, which integrates well with most IDEs and is easy to set-up.

Comment: Git and Mercurial both fit the bill, though I'm not sure if either can be integrated with PyScripter (but see http://stackoverflow.com/q/10588298/395760). This isn't necessary to be productive though. Also, the question *which* tool to use is decidedly off-topic.

Comment: `git` runs just fine without a server, and runs just fine on Windows. http://msysgit.github.io/

Comment: @delnan, can I use TortoiseGIT just on my machine (=without connecting to the github on the Web?)

Comment: @AlexTereshenkov Absolutely, and TortoiseHG too. And the non-tortoise versions of both. "Offline/local" is the default mode of operation in all *distributed* version control systems.

Comment: @delnan, alright, I got you. Would you mind wrapping the answer which I could accept later on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would strongly recommend using [mercurial](http://mercurial.selenic.com/) - it is easier to get the hang of than git and is itself written in python.

There are also both a GUI, TortoiseHg, and a web server, (hg serve or start from thg), with the web interface built in.

Comment: I've checked their website, it seems as one is supposed to operate the software with CMD-like commands. Is there a GUI for this guy?

Comment: @AlexTereshenkov: TortoiseHG. (there's even a link from the Mercurial downloads page)

Comment: EasyMercurial is a very basic GUI but largely sufficient for first time use and most importantly, simpler than TortoiseHG